# Set Font on GTK# Widget

Tags: mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I Would like to change the style of a button or menu entry by changing the font type. How con this be done cause there is no porperty on the GTK# widget for this like "Gtk.Button.Font"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ModifyFont](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aGtk.Widget.ModifyFont%28Pango.FontDescription%29) method. As per the example on the linked page:

```
button1.ModifyFont(FontDescription.FromString("Courier 16"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `button1.ModifyFont`, `button1.Child.ModifyFont` worked in my case.